# Can't "yum install" anything after install dropbox. Repository error?

Tags: repository, dropbox

Running on CentOS 6.7. I tried to install xterm with yum install xterm, but it gave me a error. I tried yum install other packages, such as gcc, same messages displayed. I notice it has something to with Dropbox, which I just installed. What happened?

```
[root@localhost william]# yum install xterm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
 * extras: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * updates: linux.mirrors.es.net
http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Dropbox. Please verify its path and try again
[root@localhost william]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.usc.edu
 * extras: reflector.westga.edu
 * updates: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Dropbox. Please verify its path and try again
[root@localhost william]# yum install geany
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
 * extras: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.lstn.net
http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Dropbox. Please verify its path and try again
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to remove any non-standard repositories from

/etc/yum.repos.d/

By the way chek if DNS/Internet is working by using pings/telnets